# Suggestions for writing this small piece of code more elegantly

Tags: python

Although it looks terrible, I am not finding a nicer/more efficient way of doing this:

```
ae    = np.arange(0.0,1,0.05)
aee   = np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345)
aef   = np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345)
random.shuffle(ae)
random.shuffle(aee)
random.shuffle(aef)
for item_a in aee:
    for item_b in ae:
        for item_c in aef: 
            rlist.append(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(item_b,item_a,item_c))
```

Ideas?

Comment: And the purpose of the above code is to generate a semi-shuffled list of color values?

Comment: Yes. That is right, at least at this section.

Comment: Not terrible at all, except that you could have used better variable names like h, s, v (for loop) and randomH, randomS, randomV (lists) for example.

Comment: Python 2.4 has only had security bugfixes since 2004. You're essentially running a 6-year-old version of the language. 2.7 is the latest, and all future development is on the 3.x series. You really need to work on updating your systems.

Comment: @Daenyth, we are using proprietary 3rd party extensions that do not run on newer versions of Python. Upgrading is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
import colorsys
hue, saturation, value = np.arange(0.0,1,0.05), np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345), np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345)
rlist= [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, saturation, value) for hue, saturation, value in
        itertools.product(random.sample(hue,len(hue)), random.sample(saturation, len(saturation)), random.sample(value, len(value)))]
print rlist
```

EDIT: random.sample from full population to avoid inplace separate shuffles

The version without itertools:

```
# without itertools
import numpy as np
import random
from pprint import pprint
import colorsys
hues, saturations, values = np.arange(0.0,1,0.05), np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345), np.arange(0.3,1.01,0.345)
rlist= [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, saturation, value)
        for hue in random.sample(hues,len(hues))
        for saturation in random.sample(saturations, len(saturations))
        for value in random.sample(values, len(values))]
pprint(rlist)
```

You can also include the definition of itertools.product from documentation (I did that in module called **it.py** in my server and used it instead of itertools):

```
product = None
from itertools import *
if not product:
    def product(*args, **kwds):
        # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
        # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
        pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
        result = [[]]
        for pool in pools:
            result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
        for prod in result:
            yield tuple(prod)
```

I use itertools normally as:

```
import itertools as it
```

But in the server it is replaced by

```
import it
```

Comment: Nice, but I can't use itertools.product in Python 2.4, but thanks.

Comment: eumiro's three fors does the same, just is not adaptable to variable amount of parameters as itertools.product. I just did not see it before posting, also thought to add to code to make it runnable.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to shuffle the `rlist`, but the initial lists, then you can try to put the last four lines into a list comprehension:

```
rlist = [ colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(b, a, c) for c in aef for b in ae for a in aee ]
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to shuffle each list in the first place because you will do a Cartesian product ... ;

```
import itertools
import colorsys


hsv_iter = itertools.product(np.arange((0, 1, 0.05),
                             np.arange((0.3,1.01,0.345),
                             np.arange((0.3,1.01,0.345))

rlist = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, lightness, saturation)
         for hue, lightness, saturation in hsv_ite]

# you can shuffle now the list if you want
random.shuffle(rlist)
```

Comment: Note, this results in more shuffling possibilities than the OP's original code.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid oneliner:

```
rlist = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(b, a, c) for c in random.sample(aef,len(aef))
                                      for b in random.sample(ae,len(ae)) 
                                      for a in random.sample(aee,len(aee))]
```

`random.sample(x,len(x))` (new in 2.3) is pretty much equivalent to `random.shuffle(x)`, but it returns a randomized copy of the list instead of `None`.

This is probably much slower than shuffling or whatever else, and you don't keep a copy of the randomized lists (if you care).